# Number of uniform n-bit strings

Tags: key-distribution

In the set of `2^n` binary strings on n-bits, how many strings have exactly equal number of 0s and 1s.

Comment: You look like you need to study basic combinatorics; this is important.

Comment: Manual B gave the exact answer; if you need an approximate answer (say, for a quick estimate), it is somewhat less than $2^n / \sqrt{n}$

Comment: fkraiem thankyou for the comment, but don't you have somthing else to do ?......

Comment: If $n$ is odd, the answer is zero.

Comment: See "central binomial coefficient".

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of permutations with repetition, as we have repeated 1s and 0s. The general formula is quite simple:
$$
P_r=\frac{n!}{n_0!n_1!...n_k!}
$$
$n$ is the number of objects (the length of the string in your case).

$n_0$, $n_1$ and $n_k$ is the number of times that the 1st object, the 2nd one and the $(k-1)$st object are repeated, respectively.

$n!$ is the factorial function ($n!=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...1$).

As we only have b objects (the length of the string in bits), but there are only two kinds of them (0 and 1), the formula is this one:
$$
f(b)=\frac{b!}{n_0!n_1!}
$$

As the number of times that 0 and 1 appear is equal to $\frac{b}{2}$:

$$
f(b)=\frac{b!}{\frac{b}{2}!\frac{b}{2}!}=\frac{b!}{(\frac{b}{2}!)^2}
$$

FUN FACT:
$$
f(2)=\frac{4\cdot3}{2\cdot1}; f(3)=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{3\cdot2\cdot1}; f(4)=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}...
$$